# How can I style one row with multiple conditions in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I have a dataframe for which I want to have some rows styled for which the indices appear in a dictionary.
After trying a bunch of things with apply, applymap, subset with row/column/IndexSlice, I still haven't found the solution for

1. Styling different cells for a specific row based on **multiple** conditions with **different colors**. (As rows & columns need to be written to excel in the same way, transposing wouldn't work(?!))
2. Grouping the styling conditions and colors for a specific row/'cat' in 1 function.
3. Styling all cells in a row conditionally based on the value of the cells in another row,but same column (ref. desired result).

***Note***: Some rows will be 'styled', others will not.

**First issue**: cat1 appears in the dictionary, so I need it styled with conditions. I would need to pass each cell in the row through a condition to apply a certain color.
After a lot of tries the code below comes 'closest' to a potential solution, but I'm getting an error when saving to excel. (It does work completely when I only use the code for 'green').

*"The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."*

`d_functions_colors={'cat1': catone_color,'cat5': catfive_color, 'cat40':catforty_color}`

```
        2020-12   2019-12   2018-12   2017-12    2016-12      ...
idx  
cat1        100       NaN        50        35          5      ...
cat2          5       NaN         7         3          2      ...
cat3       6.25       NaN      6.25      4.93       5.21      ...
avg_cat3      5         4         3         2          1      ...
max_cat3     10        20        10        30          1      ...  
cat4                                                          ...
cat5          5        20         8         9.5       25      ...
avg_cat5     10        15         8         9.5       20      ...
...

(the results for avg, max are calculated and added for some 'cats' beforehand based on multiple (other) data sources)
```

```
    def highlight_row_green(x):
        c0 = ''
        c1 = 'background-color: green'
        c2 = 'background-color: yellow'
        c3 = 'background-color: red'
         
        df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    
        m1 = x.index.astype(str).str.contains('^cat1')
    
        mask = (x[m1] >= 50).reindex(x.index, fill_value=False)
    
        df1 = df1.mask(mask, c1)
        return df1
    
    def highlight_row_yellow(x):
        c0 = ''
        c1 = 'background-color: green'
        c2 = 'background-color: yellow'
        c3 = 'background-color: red'
         
        df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    
        m1 = x.index.astype(str).str.contains('^cat1$')
    
        mask = (20 <= x[m1] < 50)
    
        df1 = df1.mask(mask, c2)
        return df1
    
    
    def highlight_row_red(x):
        c0 = ''
        c1 = 'background-color: green'
        c2 = 'background-color: yellow'
        c3 = 'background-color: red'
         
        df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    
        m1 = x.index.astype(str).str.contains('^cat1$')
    
        mask = ( x[m1] < 20)
    
        df1 = df1.mask(mask, c3)
        return df1

    def pandastoExcel(path,filename,sheetname,my_dataframe):
    outputfilepath=(path+'\\'+filename)
    if len(sheetname)>=30:
        sheetname='Default'
    else:
        pass
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(outputfilepath , engine='xlsxwriter')
    try:
        my_dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetname,index=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
    writer.save()


df_output=df.style.\
    apply(highlight_row_green, axis=None).\
    apply(highlight_row_yellow, axis=None).\
    apply(highlight_row_red, axis=None)
```

---

**Second issue**: I tried to group them, but got the same error
*"The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."*

```
def catone_color(x):
     c1 = 'background-color: green'
     c2 = 'background-color: yellow'
     c3 = 'background-color: red'
     c0 = '' 

     df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
     m1 = x.index.astype(str).str.contains('^cat1$')

     mask = (x[m1] >= 50).reindex(x.index, fill_value=False)
     masky = (20 <= x[m1] < 50)
     maskr = (x[m1] < 20)

     df1 = df1.mask(mask, c1)
     df1 = df1.mask(masky, c2)
     df1 = df1.mask(maskr, c3)
     return df1

df_output=df.style.apply(catone_color, axis=None)
```

---

**Third issue**: (Eg. cat5), styling is based on the values in cat5_avg. So the color of the 2020 cat5_value is based on the 2020 cat5_avg, the color for the 2019 cat5_value is based on the 2019 cat5_value, etc..

Tried by combining the 2 rows (eg row_values, row_avg) in a dataframe and some other stuff, but far from achieving anything.

```
            2020-12   2019-12   2018-12   2017-12    2016-12      ...
    idx  
    cat1        100       NaN        50        35          5      ...
    cat2          5       NaN         7         3          2      ...
    cat3       6.25       NaN      6.25      4.93       5.21      ...
    avg_cat3      5         4         3         2          1      ...
    max_cat3     10        20        10        30          1      ...  
    cat4                                                          ...
    cat5          5        20         8         9.5       25      ...
    avg_cat5     10        15         8         9.5       20      ...
    ...

#Idea of what I'm trying to accomplish:
for cat5_value in row_cat_5:
    If cat5_value > avg_cat5_same column:
          color = 'green'
    elif cat5_value == avg_cat5_same_column:
          color = 'yellow'
    elif cat5_value < avg_cat5_same_column:
          color = 'red'
    else:
          color=''
    return 'background-color: %s' % color

#(Background color row cat_5 would be red,green,yellow,yellow,green).  

#What I've got left from trying:
    g= 'green'
    y = 'yellow'
    r = 'red'

    m1 = val.iloc[0, :] < val.iloc[1, :]
    m2 = val.iloc[0, :] == val.iloc[1, :]
    m3 = val.iloc[0, :] > val.iloc[1, :]

    df1 = pd.DataFrame('background-color: ', index=val.index, columns=val.columns)

    df1.iloc[:,0] = np.where(m1, 'background-color: {}'.format(g), df1.iloc[0, :])
    df1.iloc[:,0] = np.where(m2, 'background-color: {}'.format(y), df1.iloc[0, :])
    df1.iloc[:,0] = np.where(m3, 'background-color: {}'.format(r), df1.iloc[0, :])
    return df1
```

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svZbm.png)

Thank you in advance,

PS: Early thanks to all contributors of which the answers served as basis for the resulting code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with openpyxl

```
 from openpyxl import Workbook,load_workbook
 from openpyxl.styles import Color, PatternFill, Font, Border
 from openpyxl.styles import colors
 from openpyxl.cell import Cell

 d_functions_colors={'cat1': catone_color,
                      'cat5': catfive_color,'cat40':catforty_color}

 wb = load_workbook(outputfilepath)
 ws = wb.active

 for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=ws.min_row, max_row=ws.max_row):
    if row[0] in d_functions_colors:
       row=d_functions_colors[row[0].value](row)

 def catone_color(row):
    for cell in row:            
        try:
          fl_cell=float(cell.value)
          if fl_cell>=50:
           #Green
           cell.fill = 
PatternFill(start_color='0000FF00',end_color='0000FF00',fill_type='solid')
          elif 50>fl_cell>=20:
           #yellow
           cell.fill = 
PatternFill(start_color='00FFFF00',end_color='00FFFF00',fill_type='solid')             
          elif 20 > fl_cell:
           #red
           cell.fill = 
PatternFill(start_color='FFFF0000',end_color='FFFF0000',fill_type='solid')
          else:
           pass
        except Exception as e:
           print(str(e))
    return row
```